# Do Zombie Horses in Minecraft spawn naturally?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do zombie horses naturally spawn? Because I want to see one in survival without using cheats.

Comment: It's possible they may naturally spawn soon considering Trap Horses were added.

Answer (score 2):

**They do not spawn naturally.**

The only way to obtain one is by using cheats, you can spawn one using the command

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3, Tame:1}
```

Comment: You don't need the tame part?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ: No, you don't need the tame part but it helps so you can ride it.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer: No**

You may only see the mob either in Creative, by spawning them (MCPE), or by summoning them. Another way is to have a horse stuck by lightning (this might be for a zombie horse though) in MCPE and maybe even in MCPC.

Here is the command (It is a bit more complex than simple /summon Zombie because it is a type of horse in the game):

/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3, Tame:1}

Comment: This is pretty much the same as another answer, which was there first.

Answer (score -1):

No. Much like the Skeleton Horse, the only way to see a Zombie horse is to spawn them in creative, or summon them with commands.

If they are struck by lightning, they may turn into a zombie.

Here is the command to spawn a Zombie horse.

/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3, Tame:1}

Comment: 1. This is basically a copy of another answer. 2. Skeleton horses do spawn in minecraft.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, it does not work without cheats.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer? It's pretty sparse as-is.